# Is it possible to have template class arguments specified by the compiler, when passed in as a parameter?

Tags: c++

Consider the following:
I'm writing a Matrix class in C++, which looks like this:

```
template<unsigned rows, unsigned cols>
class matrix
{
    ...
};
```

Now, writing the multiply method, I've come to a problem: The left - "this" - matrix must have the same number of columns which the right - "o" - matrix has rows, but how many columns o has, is irrelevant, see below:

```
const matrix<rows, rows> mul(const matrix<cols, /*This can be anything*/>&& o)
{
    ...
}
```

My question is, is there any way to tell the compiler, that it should take the template argument of o for its unknown second argument?

Comment: Just make that function a template. Class templates can have member function templates.

Comment: So then I can take the template argument of mul and put it inside the column argument of o?

Comment: Note that constant rvalue references (like the argument to your `mul` function) is almost always useless. Perhaps you really should use a constant lvalue reference, as in `const matrix<cols, ...>&` (note the single `&`)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, yes I guess, I haven't really figured out, when to use rvalue references instead of lvalue references to achieve the best result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any way to tell the compiler, that it should take the
>   template argument of o for its unknown second argument?

Yes indeed, this is exactly what templates does for you : )
Just write `mul()` as a *member function template* instead of a *member function*.

```
template<unsigned rows, unsigned cols>
class matrix
{
    ...

    template <unsigned rhsRows>
    matrix<rows, rhsRows> mul(const matrix<cols, rhsRows>& o) const
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Note: `const` was moved to made the member function template *const* instead of being *const* for the return value, as being there it can disable move semantics, and as the semantics of multiplying matrices shouldn't change any of the operands if returning a result.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the solutions are simpler, than one thinks :)

Comment: The return type was originally `matrix<rows, rows>` (`rows` twice). Additionally, there is no reason to make the return value `const`, it can disable move semantics.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point, I'm really new to move semantics and stuff, so this helps me greatly. Going to rewrite my vector and point classes now as well ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You too friend